# Autofs: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -112

Tags: centos, automount

So I have had a server 2008 file share mounted on my CentOs 7 server for about 3 months with no issues.

Today, the mount went down and refuses to go back up. Every time i try to ls -al the mounted folder I get cifs_mount failed w/return code = -112. No updates were made on either side and I have tried taking both sides completely down and bring them back up to no avail.

autofs.mymount file:

```
myshare -fstype=cifs,rw,noperm,credentials=/path/to/credentials ://<ip address>/share/
```

credential file:

```
username=user
password=password
domain=domain.local
```

I am using autofs version 5.0.7